# How can I abstract away Ansible roles?

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I have 2 different database instances in my infrastructure, each used to save different data, each running on different machines, and each of them needs different levels of availability & safety, so while both of them use Postgresql as database, since each of them plays different "role" in my infrastructure, I have written different roles in my ansible code for them to be set up and be ready to serve requests. Let's call them database `A` and `B`.
For `A` I need a replica, managed by `repmgr`, which is run on a separate machine, and I have another role in my codes that sets up replica of `A` with configuration specific to `A`. Since `A` and replica of `A` are *not* interchangeable, they don't belong to the same group in inventory file, and there I have a `A` group and a `A_replica` group, explicitly distinct.
Now, I want to add replica of `B`, using `repmgr` same as in replica of `A`, but I don't see a way to reuse codes that I've written for `A`, since they differ in:

- `hosts` that tasks of playbook are run against,
- Some variables that are used in `template` directives to generate config files. By default, I define these in `group_vars`, but I don't know how to define them in playbooks, specifically playbooks that include other (lower-level) playbooks

Is there a solution, or should I literally copy & paste the codes for `B`?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

First, for `hosts` target, you can set it as an [extra-vars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line) on the command-line ( you can find another example using extra-vars [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30662069/how-can-i-pass-variable-to-ansible-playbook-in-the-command-line) ).

If you use different variables in your template file for each of the two cases, make sure to [check if the variable is specified](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#tests) before proceeding. Then, use `host_vars` instead of `group_vars`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

> another role in my codes that sets up replica of `A` with
>   configuration specific to `A`

For maximum reuse, extract *all* configuration that could be different into variables and templates. Primary/secondary boolean, host names and ports, users and secrets. Generalizing may mean being more clever, such as using if statements in templates depending on if a replica is needed or not. Success in abstraction means you (or someone else if you publish on Galaxy!) can re-use the role in other projects.

> By default, I define these in group_vars, but I don't know how to
>   define them in playbooks, specifically playbooks that include other
>   (lower-level) playbooks

There are many places to put variables: [Variable precedence: Where should I put a variable?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable)

The admin user you always create can be a role default, an "I am a replica" boolean probably goes in a group var, the replication name of a specific database probably goes in a host var. This way you can run a play on `hosts: A_replica,B_replica` but each uses some unique configuration.

One powerful way to make "sub-classed" roles is to use [role dependencies](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#role-dependencies). Create a fully featured but abstract role `db`. Create roles for each instance of the database as `db-a` and `db-b` that each have dependencies on `db` in their meta. The A and B roles only need to provide variables that are different, and maybe a task or two.